# Can I define a fully filled grid whithout using a lot of div?

Tags: html, css, grid

The main issue I have is that I need to define a large grid. I want to use a grid because it's giving me the best results, but I can only achieve it by using a large number of  elements. Is there any other way to do it?

What I have right now is this:

```
<div class="modalDayBackground">
                        <div></div>
                        <div>8:00</div><div>10:00</div><div>12:00</div><div>14:00</div><div>16:00</div><div>18:00</div><div>20:00</div>
                        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>                           
                        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
                        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div> 

                    </div>
```

My css looks like this:

```
::deep .modalDayBackground {
    background-color: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    top: 6.5em;
    left: 0.65em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56.3em;
    column-gap: 1px;
    row-gap: 1px;
    grid-template-columns: 2.35em 5.1em 5.2em 5.1em 5.2em 5.1em 5.2em 5.5em;
    grid-template-rows:3.5em 2.7em 2.45em 2.5em 2.55em 2.55em;

}

::deep .modalDayBackground div {
    background-color: white;
    color: #8391a2; /*#bccee4;*/
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: create the grid dynamically with JS. If this is a calender, for tasks or a calendar, you should sue a table instead

Comment: Well it shows a day with more detail, it's like a zoom in. I'm working with Blazor but I think that i can use JS functions too, so I will try it.